# Cannot Resolve Symbol when importing vector asset in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am using AS 1.5.1

So I tried to import a vector asset by following this:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html

I tried to use my drawable like this:

```
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_av_timer_24dp.xml"
```

However, it was highlighted red and telling me that cannot resolve symbol.

Why is that so?

This is my whole layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="org.isg.shinobi.isg.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_av_timer_24dp.xml" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my drawable structure.
[image]

thanks!

Comment: @android:drawable/ic_av_timer_24dp.xml =>@drawable/ic_av_timer_24dp.

Comment: stll error. Cannot resolve.

Comment: Can you show your drawable and layout about this vector?

Comment: I already added an image of my drawable structure thanks!

Comment: Are you using Android Plugin for Gradle 1.5.0 or higher?You can try to click src in preview view.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps:

1. Change `app:src="@android:drawable/xyz"` to `app:srcCompat="@drawable/xyz"`
2. Add this line under **defaultConfig in build.gradle(Module:app)** - `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = "true"`